# How to show login page before showing index.html using express.static in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, static

I'm using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));` to show login page before showing index.html in Node.js.

However, it doesn't show login page before index.html...
I tried to use `app.get('/', function (req,res) {res.redirect('/login');});` but it doesn't even go through that `app.get` and doesn't redirect when it connects to localhost:4000...

my directory setup is shown below

```
myapp
  node_modules
  public
    images
    javascripts
    js
    stylesheets
    index.html
  routes
  views
    login
      login.ejs
    users
      new.ejs
    index.jade
    layout.jade
  app.js
  package.json
```

Also, I want to hold index.html in public folder and just want to display login page before that..
Is there any ways to show that??

Here is my whole code in app.js

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var redis = require('redis');
var sys = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
//Added for connecting login session
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var async = require('async');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

//connecting database
mongoose.connect("my mongoDB private address");
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once("open",function () {
  console.log("DB connected!");
});
db.on("error",function (err) {
  console.log("DB ERROR :", err);
});

var bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
  password: {type:String, required:true},
  createdAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now}
});
userSchema.pre("save", function (next){
  var user = this;
  if(!user.isModified("password")){
    return next();
  } else {
    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password);
    return next();
  }
});
userSchema.methods.authenticate = function (password) {
  var user = this;
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password,user.password);
};

var User = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);

io = io.listen(server);

app.set("view engine", 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//setting middleware for login
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(flash());

app.use(session({secret:'MySecret', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use('local-login',
  new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField : 'email',
      passwordField : 'password',
      passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
      User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        if (!user){
            req.flash("email", req.body.email);
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginError', 'No user found.'));
        }
        if (!user.authenticate(password)){
            req.flash("email", req.body.email);
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginError', 'Password does not Match.'));
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  )
);
//set home routes
//var data_1 = {email:''};

app.get('/', function (req,res) {
  res.redirect('/login');
  //req.url = '/login';
  //next();
});
app.get('/login', function (req,res) {
  res.render('login/login',{email:req.flash("email")[0], loginError:req.flash('loginError')});
});
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
  return res.redirect('/?channel='+ req.body.email);
  })(req, res, next);
});
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/login');
});

// set user routes
app.get('/users/new', function(req,res){
  res.render('users/new', {
                            formData: req.flash('formData')[0],
                            emailError: req.flash('emailError')[0],
                            passwordError: req.flash('passwordError')[0]
                          }
  );
}); // new
app.post('/users', checkUserRegValidation, function(req,res,next){
  User.create(req.body.user, function (err,user) {
    if(err) return res.json({success:false, message:err});
    res.redirect('/login');
  });
}); // create

//functions
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  }else{
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
  res.redirect('/');
}

function checkUserRegValidation(req, res, next) {
  var isValid = true;

  async.waterfall(
    [function(callback) {
      User.findOne({email: req.body.user.email, _id: {$ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}},
        function(err,user){
          if(user){
            isValid = false;
            req.flash("emailError","- This email is already resistered.");
          }
          callback(null, isValid);
        }
      );
    }], function(err, isValid) {
      if(err) return res.json({success:"false", message:err});
      if(isValid){
        return next();
      } else {
        req.flash("formData",req.body.user);
        res.redirect("back");
      }
    }
  );
}

function handler(req,res){
    console.log(req);
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', function(err,data){
                if(err){
                        res.writeHead(500);
                        return res.end('Error loading index.html');
                }

                res.writeHead(200);
                console.log("Listening on port 3000");
                res.end(data);
        });

        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/style.css', function(err,data){
                if(err){
                        res.writeHead(500);
                        return res.end('Error loading index.html');
                }

                res.writeHead(200);
                console.log("Listening on port 3000");
                res.end(data);
        });
}

io.sockets.addListener('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("connceted : " + socket.id);

    var subscriber = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost');
    subscriber.psubscribe("*");
    subscriber.on("pmessage", function(pattern, channel, message) {
        //console.log(message);
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("disconnceted : " + socket.id);
        subscriber.quit();
    });

    socket.on('close', function() {
        console.log("close");
        subscriber.quit();
    });
});

app.listen(4000, function(){
  console.log('Server On!!!');
});
```

Should I use another express to display login page? or what should I do here?
I'm actually newbie in node.js.

Can anybody please help me out here??

Thank you..

**EDIT:** My whole code for app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Added for connecting login session
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var async = require('async');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

//connecting database
mongoose.connect("private mongoDB address");
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once("open",function () {
  console.log("DB connected!");
});
db.on("error",function (err) {
  console.log("DB ERROR :", err);
});

var bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
  password: {type:String, required:true},
  createdAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now}
});
userSchema.pre("save", function (next){
  var user = this;
  if(!user.isModified("password")){
    return next();
  } else {
    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password);
    return next();
  }
});
userSchema.methods.authenticate = function (password) {
  var user = this;
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password,user.password);
};

var User = mongoose.model('user',userSchema);

app.set("view engine", 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//setting middleware for login
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(flash());

app.use(session({secret:'MySecret', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  //console.log('serializeUser()', user);
  done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  //console.log('deserializeUser()', user);
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
var global_username = '';
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use('local-login',
  new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField : 'email',
      passwordField : 'password',
      passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
      User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        if (!user){
            req.flash("email", req.body.email);
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginError', 'No user found.'));
        }
        if (!user.authenticate(password)){
            req.flash("email", req.body.email);
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginError', 'Password does not Match.'));
        }
        var email_address = req.body.email;
        var username = email_address.substring(0, email_address.lastIndexOf("@"));
        global_username = username;
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  )
);
//set home routes
app.get('*', loggedInCheck);   ------------------>This is the code with loggedInCheck function. I created another one instead of isLoggedIn function
app.get('/login', function (req,res) {
  res.render('login/login',{email:req.flash("email")[0], loginError:req.flash('loginError')});
});

app.post('/login',
  function (req,res,next){
    next();
  }, passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/posts',
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : true
  })
);


app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/login');
});
// set user routes
app.get('/users/new', function(req,res){
  res.render('users/new', {
                            formData: req.flash('formData')[0],
                            emailError: req.flash('emailError')[0],
                            passwordError: req.flash('passwordError')[0]
                          }
  );
}); // new
app.post('/users', checkUserRegValidation, function(req,res,next){
  User.create(req.body.user, function (err,user) {
    if(err) return res.json({success:false, message:err});
    res.redirect('/login');
  });
}); // create

app.get('/posts', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/status.html?channel=' + global_username);
});

//functions
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    console.log("Authenticated");
    console.log("Accessing to status.html");
    return next();

  }else{
    console.log("Unauthorized Attempt");
    res.redirect('/login');

  }
}

function loggedInCheck(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.redirect('/status.html?channel=' + global_username);

  }else{
    console.log("Unauthorized Attempt");
    res.redirect('/login');

  }
}


server.listen(5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Express, the order of calls matters.

In your case, the call to `app.use (express.static...` is done before the `app.get ('/'...` so it has a higher priority.
And since `express.static` ends the middleware chain, it will never call your `app.get`.

One possible solution would be to place your `app.get` above the `app.use (express.static`.

But, if you do so, you will never be able to show your `index.html`. You could add a condition to choose whether you redirect to `/login` or call `next ()` to continue the middleware chain.

**Edit**

After taking a deeper look at your code, you seem to have a middleware `isLoggedIn` doing the proper logic.

You can keep the order of middlewares unchanged and do `app.get('*', isLoggedIn);`

This will call your middleware for any `GET` request.

Comment: @Ninetaindedo Thank you for replying me back. It is not working though.. hm.. Can I make one more express() variable? and try? will it be fine?

Comment: There is no need to do such a thing. How does it not work ? What have you done and have you tried putting some log in the `app.get ('/'` function.

Comment: @Ninetaindedo I put 'app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); between app.get('/login', function and app.post('/login', function and after put correct login id and password, it stays at login page.. :'(

Comment: Let me edit my answer, I found something in your code that should help you better

Comment: @Ninetaindedo Thank you so much for helping me out! I'll wait.. :)

Comment: @Ninetendedo Thank you for helping me out! :) However, still gives me bunch of errors.. :'(  ha....... :'( I left the app.use(express.static that where it suppose. and followed as you said but gives me bunch of errors..

Comment: If you have done what I say in my edit you can keep `app.use (express.static` where it is in your post and put the `app.get ('*'` right above it. Also completely remove your `app.get ('/'` since it's now handled by `isLoggedIn`. After that what does it say/do ?

Comment: It says Error: Can't set headers after they sent. :'( Thank you for helping me out! :'(

Comment: Yeah I see why : in your `isLoggedIn` function remive the last line `res.redirect('/');` otherwise it will be called after your else even though it makes no sense.

Comment: Oh man... it gives me error 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' now on web page.. sorry for taking your time...

Comment: Of course because `/login` will redirect to `/login` indefinitely. You can update `isLoggedIn` to call `next ()` if the user is logged in OR if the requested url matches `/login`. You are close, I think you can handle this last (hopefully) problem by yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and really sorry for taking your time.. :) I'll try out! :)

Comment: Hey, can you help me out with isLoggedin function...? I get errors still for too many redirects.. :'(

Comment: Could you append the current code in your main post, please ? You put an **Edit** and put the code below.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response.. I edited my whole code.

Comment: I just changed name of html file from index.html to status.html. And now I wanted to check login and redirect all before it goes to status.html after logging in :'( and kept giving me too many redirects.. :'(

Comment: Same thing I said in my answer : **the order matters** if you `app.get ('*')` before `app.get ('/login')` login will never be reached because '*' will match before '/login' is even tested. Swap the order of those lines.

Answer (score 2):

**You want to load '/login' before '/index.html'** I assume you want the user to login before they reach the home page. 
Also, instead of redirecting, try RENDERING.

Before using this code, reset your isLoggedIn back to default.

```
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     if(!isLoggedIn)
      res.render('login')
     else 
       res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hie, I split your app.js file into multiple parts in an effort to isolate the router, the files are given below.

app.js

```
var express = require('./express'),
mongoose = require('./mongoose'),
passport = require('./passport');

var db = mongoose();
var app = express();
var passport = passport();

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server running on port: ' + 3000);
});
```

express.js

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var redis = require('redis');
var sys = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
//Added for connecting login session
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var async = require('async');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

module.exports = function() {
io = io.listen(server);

app.set("view engine", 'ejs');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//setting middleware for login
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(flash());

app.use(session({secret: 'MySecret', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./passport');
require('./router')(app);

io.sockets.addListener('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("connceted : " + socket.id);

    var subscriber = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost');
    subscriber.psubscribe("*");
    subscriber.on("pmessage", function (pattern, channel, message) {
        //console.log(message);
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("disconnceted : " + socket.id);
        subscriber.quit();
    });

    socket.on('close', function () {
        console.log("close");
        subscriber.quit();
    });
});

return app;
};
```

mongoose.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function() {
var db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/stacktest");

require('./model');

return db;
};
```

model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
email: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
password: {type:String, required:true},
createdAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now}
});

userSchema.pre("save", function (next){
var user = this;
if(!user.isModified("password")){
    return next();
} else {
    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password);
    return next();
}
});

userSchema.methods.authenticate = function (password) {
var user = this;
return bcrypt.compareSync(password,user.password);
};

mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
```

passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

module.exports = function() {
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
    });
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use('local-login',
    new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (req, email, password, done) {
            User.findOne({'email': email}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) return done(err);

                if (!user) {
                    req.flash("email", req.body.email);
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginError', 'No user found.'));
                }
                if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
                    req.flash("email", req.body.email);
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginError', 'Password does not Match.'));
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    )
);
};
```

And Finally router.js

```
var passport = require('./passport');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/login');
    //req.url = '/login';
    //next();
});
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login', {email: req.flash("email")[0], loginError: req.flash('loginError')});
});
app.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        return res.redirect('/?channel=' + req.body.email);
    })(req, res, next);
});
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/login');
});

// set user routes
app.get('/users/new', function (req, res) {
    res.render('users/new', {
            formData: req.flash('formData')[0],
            emailError: req.flash('emailError')[0],
            passwordError: req.flash('passwordError')[0]
        }
    );
}); // new

};
```

I could not locate the 'checkUserRegValidation' so I had to remove (as I thought it was not directly related to the error in question), I then made two ejs files, with simple heading identifying the page (whether it the login page or index) and I got your expected result (The login page was rendered when put localhost://3000 in my browser). So maybe you could try to isolate your files if it helps, sorry for the long answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying the answer. :) Can you let me know the directory settings if you have a time?? :'(

Comment: Also, can I put my function handler in express.js too?

Comment: @paulc1111 yes, that's where it should be placed, all files are in the root folder ( hence the './' to open files), except the views where I do not have a login folder but just the login.ejs and index.ejs